# Determine Why a Call to `GET_LOCK` Failed

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to determine **why** a call to MySQL's `GET_LOCK` function failed (i.e. returned 0?), or tell me why my naive understanding of the problem below is incorrect?

Per [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock)

> Tries to obtain a lock with a name given by the string str, using a timeout of timeout seconds. Returns 1 if the lock was obtained successfully, 0 if the attempt timed out (for example, because another client has previously locked the name)

I'm debugging an application that attempts to get a lock using the following SQL

```
SELECT GET_LOCK('thinkup_2_b2_dev.crawler', 1) AS result
```

Whenever this code runs from a PHP context, `result` is always zero.  This happens on my local development machine, and happened the first time I ran the application.  In other worlds, I'm relatively sure there's no previous lock.

<s>This is buoyed by the fact that, when I connect to the database with a third party tool (specifically, SequelPro) and run the following command</s>

<s>`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`</s>;

<s>I don't see any mention of the lock (it's my understanding that these sorts of locks will show up when I run `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`).  All I see is the single row (Which I believe corresponds to the connection I'm currently using.)</s>

<s>`9617    root    localhost   thinkup_2_b2_dev    Query   0   NULL    SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`</s>

(Based on some independent tests, it appears that `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` doesn't show these sort of locks)

Is there a way to get MySQL to tell me why it's returning zero from a call to `get_lock`?  If not, does anyone have any ideas for debugging this problem further?

Comment: Wild unlikely-to-be-right stab in the dark, does the act of taking the lock take more than 1 second? E.g. server does not have sufficient resources to take a lock in < 1s.

Comment: Also the other functions `IS_FREE_LOCK` and `IS_USED_LOCK` might be useful for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation states, the function returns zero only when it times out. This would suggest that the timeout of 1 second was hit even if no session holds the lock. To verify that this is indeed the case, I'd recommend trying with a larger timeout (e.g. 10 seconds).

If the function returns zero even with a larger timeout, then there is a systematic problem with the particular lock. If the timeout of 1 second is indeed too short and the 10 second timeout solves it, I'd recommend opening a bug report as it is not expected behavior.